# How to find export option in iReport?

Tags: ireport

I am working on `iReport`. where i need to find the Export option like (PDF/Excel) dynamically,
because i need to pass the export type as parameter into the pages.

Can anyone give some suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

personally, I do this on Runtime, for example if I want to output on a pdf file

```
JRAbstractExporter exporter;
exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
```

or Excel

```
JRAbstractExporter exporter;
exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
```

all this using java and jasperreports library

Comment: Have u worked on iReport..my target is to hide a column is PDF exporter, but the column should display on Excel exporter

Comment: You can do this by using a boolean variable to pass when you build your report

Comment: Fine good...that's was i am asking how to do it....because i need to find the exporter what it is.

Comment: are you using Java in your application?